# Seemingly missing information from Facebook's Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Consider the following:
Friend with ID 1 is in a relationship and has his birthday data filled in as well
Friend with ID 2 is also in a relationship and has his birthday data filled in too

Both of users with ID 1 and 2 are friends and if I login to Facebook, I can see the above mentioned information without any problem.

Then I make a call to the Graph API using the Facebook SDK, so I make something similar to:

```
$this->_facebook->api("/1");
```

For this ID, in the returned array I can see the relationship status, the birthday etc.

However

```
$this->_facebook->api("/2");
```

does not return this information, only the absolute basics such as 'name', 'id' and 'gender' - I'm using a simple print_r() statment to dump the returned array. When initiating the login I send the right permissions via the 'scope' parameter (and hence I can see the information belonging to user with ID 1).

So the question is: If I see the birthday and rel status for both users on the interface, why I only see one via the api calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming in your example there, that user '1' uses your app or is a friend of a user of your app (assuming you have the appropriate friends_* permission)?

Other users' information won't be available via the API - even if you can infer that information through other pieces of data you have access to - in general you can only access data on behalf of your app's users and their friends, and privacy settings can override what you can access about your users' friends, even if your user can see the info on facebook.com

Comment: Igy - that's an interesting point. At the moment I'm the only one who's using this application, it's not yet released. Therefore user with ID 1 nor with ID 2 is using the application, however I still can see the bday of user '1', and this is what baffles me. Both user 1 and 2 are my friends (me, being the one who uses the app). Re the friends_* permissions, I won't see User 1's details if I wouldn't have the right permissions, but I do see that.

Comment: Users can also choose to hide certain data from apps their friends use, even if those friends can see the data on facebook.com - this setting is currently found under Privacy Settings -> Apps -> Apps Others Use, and currently looks like this: http://imgur.com/d63jzmq

Comment: That's it. I couldn't find this in my own privacy settings. Thanks Igy, you've been a great help!